# Pythonic design for handling set modification during iteration

Tags: python, loops, set, iteration, traversal

I am doing a sort of graph traversal with sets.

I have a defaultdict(set) of node keys, and the set contains other nodes in the graph that the key node has an edge to.

In my traversal, I look for two different edges of a given node.  If they are connected by an edge, I disconnect them.  If they are not connected, I connect them and disconnect them from the current node.  Something like:

```
for e1 in edgemap[curr]:
    for e2 in edgemap[curr]:
        if e1 != e2:
            if e1 in edgemap[e2]:
                edgemap[e2].remove(e1)
                edgemap[e1].remove(e2)
            else:
                edgemap[e1].add(e2)
                edgemap[e2].add(e1)
                edgemap[curr].remove(e1)
                edgemap[curr].remove(e2)
```

Of course, this code won't work at all.  I am modifying a set during iteration.  Typically, when I want to make modifications, I would iterate edgemap[_].copy().
However, in this case, I actually want the modification to take effect immediately..  So if the "else" condition was executed, with this design, we would need to break out of our for loops and start over.

At the moment I think I will use this:

```
while 1:
    match = False
    for e1 in edgemap[curr].copy():
        for e2 in edgemap[curr].copy():
            if e1 != e2:
                match = True
                if e1 in edgemap[e2]:
                    edgemap[e2].remove(e1)
                    edgemap[e1].remove(e2)
                else:
                    edgemap[e1].add(e2)
                    edgemap[e2].add(e1)
                    edgemap[curr].remove(e1)
                    edgemap[curr].remove(e2)
                    edgemap[e1].remove(curr)
                    edgemap[e2].remove(curr)

                break
        if match:
            break
```

But I am still such a beginner programmer.. and this feels really awkward.  Is there a better way that I can design this?

Comment: "However, in this case, I actually want the modification to take effect immediately." Why? What is this actually supposed to do? You should probably first make a list of thing you want to do (while iterating through these containers) and then apply all of the changes outside of the loop. But that will have a similar effect as iterating through a copy...

Comment: I want the modification to take place immediately, because the modification of my graph depends on whether or not an edge is there.  And, if I remove or add an edge, the next modification may depend upon the last addition or removal.

Comment: I still don't understand what the correct behaviour of this should be. If each step depends on the previous step, they should probably be separated, but the code you showed is not clear. For instance, your second example will always find only the first two edges `edgemap[curr]` because they will be different and then will break regardless of anything else.

Comment: I am sure that this is buggy, but while you are right that it will only find the first two edges that are not the same - it will likely remove them.  So when it starts over, it finds different edges, rather than trying to make further modifications to the graph which are dependent upon edges that should have already been removed.

Comment: If you want each step to consider the changes used in the previous step, then the final graph depends on the order of traversal. But sets are unordered so the whole thing is indeterminate.

Comment: I think that is a completely different discussion that would potentially be very long and isn't really related to the issue I am seeking assistance with.

Comment: But it actually is. This is clearly an X-Y problem. You should find the right solution for the original problem, rather than seeking _"Pythonic design for handling set modification during iteration"_ because there is no such thing.